# Jquery nested $.GET calls do not work?

Tags: jquery, callback, get, nested

I'm finding that nested calls to $.get don't work in JQuery.   I've boiled down my situation to something like below.   The first call to $.get is made and then the callback
function makes a second call to $.get if a condition is true.   The second call doesn't seem to get made even though I see the alert with the condition as true.

Has anyone gotten nesting like this to work?

```
function callbackFn (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    alert("About to make call.  Condition is " + someCondition);
    if (someCondition) {
        $.get("localhost:8080/MyServlet?action=bar");
    }
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com"

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("localhost:8080/MyServlet?action=foo", callbackFn);

}
```

Comment: you're changing the document location before the second one has a chance to do anything (`$.get` is asynchronous)

Comment: strictly speaking the second call should be a post.   It is merely informing the server of something and doesn't need any return values so its OK that it goes to the next page before the second call finishes

Answer (score 0):

It is better to chain different ajax requests, since they are asynch. Chaining is best done with .succes() .complete()

Comment: Turns out that my error was a bad argument to the URL of the second call to $.get().   Nested $.get works fine and jsfiddle is a worthwhile tool for testing out javascript and jquery ideas.

Comment: You shouldn't nest them in the way you do. Maybe it works fine while testing, but it sometimes might occur that the response of the first request takes longer, the second already start, causing unriabilty. You'll find out... Always use ajax callbacks like success, complete and error

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gMGCb/1/) (using the jsfiddle "/echo/html/" for testing AJAX):

```
function callbackFn (data) {
    alert(data);
    if(data === 'First POST') {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/echo/html/",
          data: {
                html: 'Second POST'
                },
          success: callbackFn,
          dataType: "HTML"
        });
    }
}

$(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/echo/html/",
      data: {
            html: 'First POST'
            },
      success: callbackFn,
      dataType: "HTML"
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey this jfiddle is a cool tool.   So I recoded your fiddle with $.get and it works.  My original post was boiled down from a more complex piece of code,  so I'll have to build another example closer to the actual code to see if/when I can get the fiddle to fail.